# Ruby Rails attr_encrypted format encrypted attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) and I want to get formatted attribute whenever I access encrypted attribute - is there any way of doing this?

The model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_encrypted :balance, key: 'some super secret key', marshal: true
end
```

And I want to be able to access balance and get `Money` object:
`Money.new(balance, currency)`

Is there possibility to make `user.balance` return this stright away (without additional methods like `user.balance_to_money`?

I have tried to somehow  "extend" `attr_encrypted` behaviour (defined attribute getters) but I am not sure how to achieve this.

I have tried using custom `Marshal` object, but It won't work since I have to access user's currency from the database (Marshaler won't have access to this)

```
  attr_encrypted :balance, key: 'some super secret key', marshal: true, marshaler: BalanceMarshaler
  module BalanceMarshaler
    extend self

    def dump(data) 
      data.to_s
    end

    def load(data)
      number = Marshal.load(data)
      Money.new(number, currency)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Instead of `marshaler`, you can try overriding [only `load_method`](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted), which should give you better access to other properties.

Comment: Oops, link was not anchored. Here: https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted#the-marshal-dump_method-and-load_method-options

Comment: What kind of object is `balance`?  It would be weird to me to have a reader return a `Money` object in this case, since you couldn't just assign that back to `balance` for writing.

Comment: @Joe I am working on some legacy codebase and changing encryption logic, User class used to overload `balance` and `balance=` methods (I had to move from this because It won't work with attr_encrypted, and honestly I hate that Idea)

Comment: Could you use a different/new column in activerecord allowing you to keep using the `balance` accessors?

Comment: @Joe I have also thought of that and It should work... I think I will have to go with Your suggestion or change all `balance` occurrences with smth like `balance_to_money`, will see which one takes less effort and looks better. Thanks!

Feel free to add it as separate answer so I will be able to pick it as best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to maintain an accessor that treats `balance` as a `Money` constructor, you could sidestep the issue of overriding the behavior and just use a different column.

e.g. `balance_new` or whatever, and then create an accessor for `.balance` that creates a `Money` object from `balance_new`...